# How to toggle a Boolean in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, boolean

I am struggling to toggle a `Boolean` state from true to false when the result is `undefined`. I have tried a lot but didn't work.

The boolean state in constructor is defined as follows :

```
class UserInfo extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    token : '',
    isVisible : true,
   };
}
```

This function should check if `token` holds a value or `undefined` and then continue to execute the right condition accordingly. However, when `token` is `undefined` the `isVisible` is not getting toggled to false and it will remain true no matter what.

Any suggestions I would be much appreciated.

```
 ToggleFunction = (token) => {
    if (this.state.token === undefined){
      this.setState({
        isVisible: !this.state.isVisible,
        });   
  }
  else {
    this.setState(state => ({

      isVisible: state.isVisible


    }));
  }
};
```

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: In your example declaring the class, there is not a closing bracket for class. Is this only a typo in the question?

Comment: it is a typo, that's not the issue but thanks for that

Comment: Couple of things, because I don't know the context of your app: A) `token` is never used, instead it's `state.token`. Is this intentional? B) if `state.token === undefined`, then `state.isVisible` is set to the opposite of `state.isVisible`. In your description, you say it should be set to false always

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was using `this.state.token` instead of `token`, causing to skip the `if` condition and always execute `else`. Thanks for your attention

Comment: So you solve it?

Comment: of course i did

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped. I went ahead and posted it as an answer in case anyone stumbles across this

Answer (score 0):

In your ToggleFunction, you're checking `this.state.token === undefined` as opposed to `token === undefined` from the parameter of the method call.

Try:

```js
ToggleFunction = (token) => {
    if (token === undefined){
      this.setState({
        isVisible: !this.state.isVisible,
        });   
  }
  else {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isVisible: state.isVisible
    }));
  }
};
```